# accurately move an object in linear steps with electro motor

Tags: sensor, motor, distance, movement

How would you tackle the problem of moving an 1-2 kg object in a linear fashion from point A to B to C and than back to point A and so on? Points A,B,C are fixed and require high accuracy. This image shows what I mean:

[image]

I am a skilled developer, but never learned how to connect programs to physical world. I guess I would need 2 electro motors and a strap between them, but I don't know how to program the motor to behave in the way I want, nor how to move the object. I have access to Raspberry PI and I could also get Arduino. The best option for me would be to get a commercially available tool that does what I need, but I haven't yet found one.

Comment: this question is by far too broad. I'd recommend you look at all the self-made CNC machines, which do exactly that, to get an understanding of the different ways this can be solved.

Comment: Look into linear and rotary position sensors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a linear slide. These are available ready made in a huge range of sizes, load bearing and speeds.

[image]

*Figure 1. A random image selection from [Newmark Systems](http://www.newmarksystems.com/linear-positioners/etl-series-linear-slide/) shows a screw driven slide.*

- Generally your required speed and load will determine whether to go for a belt drive (fast) or screw (high load).
- You will then need to decide on a drive system - typically stepper or servo. Stepper is simple and cheap and good enough for many applications provided they are unlikely to stall. Servo uses encoder feedback so it can detect and signal positioning errors.

If you have a simple sequence of steps you may find a programmable controller to do that automatically. Typically these will have an LCD and keypad to allow you to enter preset stop positions which are selected by digital (on/off) inputs to the device. Others will be programmed by PC but still use the digital inputs. Digital outputs will signal busy/ready and fault.

There are also many DIY linear slide mechanisms used on CNC, 3D printers, etc.

Regarding your high accuracy requirement you need to watch out for backlash (typically a little play in the drive) and the effect of step size if using stepper drive.

Finally, you are going to have to make some power calculations based on the required acceleration and deceleration. (Your application will be simple as the load will not be accelerated by gravity.) Many of the slide manufacturers will have online tools for this. Have a look at (another random link) [Why RMS torque is important for motor sizing](http://www.linearmotiontips.com/why-rms-torque-is-important-for-motor-sizing/) to get you in the mood.

Comment: This is a great answer! I've been looking for a linear slide thats is 3-5m long, but there seems none. Do you know if such slides commercially exist?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a linear slider as pointed out in the first answer or you could make or fabricate your own lead screw mechanism and couple the shaft with a stepper motor or an absolute encoder. You'll need to map the distances you need to cover to the step sizes or revolutions or you could use distances and convert them to revs for an encoder.

[image]

Figure 1:A simple lead screw mechanism